# OSError: No wkhtmltoimage executable found: "b''"

Tags: python

Code is below

```
import imgkit
imgkit.from_url('http://google.com', 'out.jpg')
```

FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)

I have already installed  !pip install imgkit

https://pypi.org/project/imgkit/

from the comment section

```
import  wkhtmltopdf 
import   imgkit
imgkit.from_url('http://google.com', 'out.jpg')
```

I got main error

Comment: You need to install `wkhtmltopdf` too

Comment: @ZWang i installed that too,

Comment: no need to import wkhtmltopdf, just need to install. Which system are you on (Windows/Linux) and which version of python are you using?

Answer (score 1):

A solution for Windows systems. Replace the path with your own path for the executable file.

```
con = imgkit.config(wkhtmltoimage='C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltoimage.exe')
imgkit.from_string(myString, 'out.jpg', config=con)
```

Same will go for the `from_url` function.